# HSL vs HSI color spaces

Tags: image-processing, colors, computer-vision

I can't understand the difference between HSL and HSI. Are they the same? Do you use the same algorithm to convert RGB -> HSL and RGB -> HSI?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSI_color_space) should explain everything you need to know.

Comment: If I understood that I would not have asked.

Comment: http://www.huevaluechroma.com/094.php

Comment: @user1486293: The article explains the difference between HSL, HSV and HSI, and gives conversion formulae.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, that is the most complete reference I've ever seen on the subject. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a comparison between HSV / HSL / HSI color spaces.
I think it's important to keep in mind that these models come from a projection of the RGB cube.
For more details on this, check the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) page (specially this [figure](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hsl-and-hsv.svg#/media/File:Hsl-and-hsv.svg)) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39147465/19988462) on Stack Overflow.

### Hue

Their hues are approximately the same. For HSI [1]:

[image: formula_hue_HSI]

in which `v_x` and `v_y` are the coordinates from the resulting RGB vector and `R`, `G` and `B` were already normalised to the range [0,1] (i.e. divide the values from the range [0,255] by 255).
If `v_y<0`, the correction `H = 360° - θ` is needed (otherwise, `H = θ`).
You may also find different formulae/algorithms depending on the text, but wielding same results.

For HSL and HSV, we first calculate the (normalised) chroma: `C = M - m = max(R,G,B) - min(R,G,B)` (again, with RGB already normalised to the range [0,1]).
Then we use the piece-wise formulation:

[image: formula_hue_HSL_HSV]

Finally, `H = H' * 60°`. If `C = 0`, we may declare `H = 0°`.

### Saturation and Value/Lightness/Intensity

The expressions for saturation and value/lightness/intensity are shown below:

[image: HSV vs HSL]
[image: HSI]

### Sources and References

Saturation and V/L/I figures source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Lightness)

[1] Rafael C. Gonzalez, Richard E. Woods. *Digital Image Processing*, 4ed. New York, NY: Pearson. 2018. ISBN-13: 9780133356724. sec. 7.2: Color Models.

Answer (score -1):

They are not the same.  You cannot use the same functions to convert from RGB.

Comment: Can you please explain the differences a little bit more?