# How Chrome DevTools' color picker calculates cursors positions from input RGB color?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, color-picker

I'm implementing a color picker using HTML5 canvas. It is the same kind as that of Chrome DevTools.

How to restore cursors on both canvases when a user inserts values through the inputs?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. HSL(Hue, Saturation, Lightness) is needed
2. Convert the input value RGB to HSL ([RGB to HSL conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39118528/rgb-to-hsl-conversion))
3. The slider in your picture, represent the `Hue` value
4. And the color palette, from top to bottom, represent the `Lightness` 0%~100%; from left to right, represent the `Saturation` 0%~100%

Comment: This almost works. The problem is that `Lightness` does not lay on the canvas as `X` coordinate of the cursors. Because its values are: top left: 100%, top right 50%, bottom left: 0 bottom right: 0.

Comment: Okay, I managed to fix the problem by replacing HSL with HSV.