# Haskell domain coloring with the 'hip' library using the HSI color space

Tags: haskell, image-processing, graphical-programming

The Hakell library **hip** allows to do 2D images processing and it provides several color spaces, such as the well known RGB space.

I'm using this [**hip**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hip-1.0.1/docs/Graphics-Image-ColorSpace.html#t:ColorSpace) library to do some 2D images.

For example, I did this image with the RGB color space using a custom color map (and an elliptic function)

[image]

Now I would like to use another color map with the HSI color space. I don't understand what happens: each time my color map calculates a H (hue) value, I get an error such as "*** Exception: HSI pixel is not properly scaled, Hue: 120.0". However the doc
found on Google claims that the H value ranges from 0 to 360. So why a value such as 120.0 is not valid?

Comment: context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76931479/haskell-domain-coloring-with-the-hip-library-using-the-hsi-color-space and specifically my comment pointing out how your idea of the value range (360 degrees) directly contradicted the piece of code you posted previously (it involves fractions and multiples of *pi*).

Comment: @4castle If you like it, I have more here : <https://github.com/stla/jacobi>.

Answer (score 1):

The doc of **hip** itself says nothing about the range but we can look at the code:

Here is the relevant source code. However not everyting is defined, such as `getRGB`, but after many trials-errors, I managed to understand.

It is clear from this code that the range of H is not [0, 360], but rather [0, 1] or [0, 2pi] (we will see).

```hs
instance Elevator e => ToRGB HSI e where
  toPixelRGB (fmap toDouble -> PixelHSI h' s i) = getRGB (h'*2*pi) where
    !is = i*s
    !second = i - is
    getFirst !a !b = i + is*cos a/cos b
    {-# INLINE getFirst #-}
    getThird !v1 !v2 = i + 2*is + v1 - v2
    {-# INLINE getThird #-}
    getRGB h
      | h < 0      = error ("HSI pixel is not properly scaled, Hue: "++show h')
      | h < 2*pi/3 = let !r = getFirst h (pi/3 - h)
                         !b = second
                         !g = getThird b r
                     in PixelRGB r g b  
      | h < 4*pi/3 = let !g = getFirst (h - 2*pi/3) (h + pi)
                         !r = second
                         !b = getThird r g
                     in PixelRGB r g b
      | h < 2*pi   = let !b = getFirst (h - 4*pi/3) (2*pi - pi/3 - h)
                         !g = second
                         !r = getThird g b
                     in PixelRGB r g b
      | otherwise  = error ("HSI pixel is not properly scaled, Hue: "++show h')
    {-# INLINE getRGB #-}
  {-# INLINE toPixelRGB #-}
```

Based on this code, I made some progress. First, the range is indeed not [0, 360], contrary to the Google claims.

Here is my color map:

```hs
colorMap2 :: Complex Double -> (Double, Double, Double)
colorMap2 z =
    let a = phase z
    in 
    let arg = if a < 0 
        then a + pi 
        else a
    in
    let h = min (arg/2/pi) 0.9999999
    in 
    let w = 2 * pi * log(1 + abs arg)
    in 
    let s = sqrt((1.0 + sin w ) / 2.0)
    in 
    let l = (1.0 + cos w ) / 2.0
    in 
    (h, s, l)
```

Observe this line: `let h = min (arg/2/pi) 0.9999999`. The rest is the stuff for my color map. The H value (denoted by `h` here) ranges from 0 to almost 1. I don't take exactly 1 because I encountered some `NaN` when the value was exactly 1.

Moreover, my experiments show that S and I must lie between 0 and 1 I think, not between 0 and 100 as claimed on Google.

Finally it works, but this color map is not pretty for this example:

[image]

Comment: @DanielWagner Because there's a `h'`.

Comment: Absolutely right. My apologies.

Comment: @DanielWagner The clipiing to 0.9999999 is necessary, otherwise `h` is `NaN` (because not < 2*pi).

Comment: @DanielWagner In fact, originally I implemented the elliptic functions in R, then in Haskell. I'm pretty sure the results are the same. Oddly, I cannot reproduce the images I did in R. There may be an error in my implementation of the figures.

Comment: Given the variable names in your code, perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11234824/791604) is relevant to your interests.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thre's a routine in **hip** which converts between the different color spaces. Oddly, the color spaces HSV and HSL are not available.